# How to center a header with h1 and remove background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing my first website and I'm using Bootstrap.
I've done my nav and I'm happy with the way it looks, but then I'm trying to create a header and center it horizontally and vertically and that's where I fail.

My page looks like this: http://prntscr.com/8fb0pu

Then I add a header h1 and it gets white background(http://prntscr.com/8fb18g) and I'm not able to center it.

How do I center the header horizontally and vertically and get rid of that white background?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsbin.com/supacehoqo/edit?html,css,output
It's without boostrap so it's a bit different

Comment: Try putting display:inline on header. Try "margin:0 auto" on header also.

Comment: doesn't help my friend

Comment: Need some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood the requirements correctly, is this what you are trying to achieve?

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="absolute-center">
    <h1>Web Developer</h1>
  </div>
<header>
```

CSS

```
header {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.absolute-center {
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
header {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.absolute-center {
  position: relative;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="absolute-center">
    <h1>Web Developer</h1>
  </div>
<header>
```

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: one more question : http://prntscr.com/8fbf18
It's not quite in center vertically, why?
and how to make it responsive?

Comment: try adjusting the `height` percentage of the `header` css to something smaller (e.g. `height: 20%;`)